# How to Pivot the Results of a Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot, unpivot

I have a stored procedure that returns data in the format of:

```
Date  |  Unit A Count  |  Unit B Count  |  Unit C Count
2010  |         335    |          52    |         540
2011  |         384    |          70    |         556
2012  |         145    |          54    |         345
```

Internally this stored procedure makes a call to another stored procedure, so I can't nest it again.
What I'm after is a way to pivot the above output so it looks like this:

```
              |  2010  |  2011  |  2012
Unit A Count  |   335  |   384  |   145
Unit B Count  |    52  |    70  |    54
Unit C Count  |   540  |   556  |   345
```

Edit: The StorProc is called with 3 parameters and I do need to keep the original output.

Any ideas?

I'm using SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2008, C# with the output going to an .aspx page.

Comment: You can do that using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transform the results of your stored procedure, then you will need to use [UNPIVOT and PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to get your final product:

See a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a896/1)

```
select *
from 
(
    select date, value, unit
    from 
    (
        select *
        from t1
    ) x
    unpivot ([value] for unit in ([unita], [unitb], [unitc])) u
) a
pivot
(
    sum(value)
    for date in ([2010], [2011], [2012])
) p
```

You want to transform these values in your store procedure, then you would have to post that full query so we could see it.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately (for me), I have to keep the format of the original output available. I was just trying to avoid writing another stored proc. that is only slightly different from the existing one.